c# [FromForm] List<IFormFile> always results in null
I want to test an REST API endpoint written in C# (.NET 8.0).
The endpoint /import should take multiple files from the TestFiles folder:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.MapPost("/import", Import).DisableAntiforgery();

static async Task<IResult> Import([FromForm] List<IFormFile> xyz)
{
    if (xyz == null || xyz.Count == 0)
    {
        return Results.BadRequest("No files were provided.");
    }

    // This is never reached !!!

    return Results.Ok();
}

app.Run();

The test looks like this:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace Importer.Tests
{
    public class IntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory) : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory = factory;
        private readonly string _testFilesPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "TestFiles");

        private MultipartFormDataContent CreateMultipartFormDataFromTestFiles(List<string> fileNames)
        {
            var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
            {
                string filepath = Path.Combine(_testFilesPath, fileName);
                var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
                var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
                fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
                formContent.Add(fileContent, "xyz", fileName);
                // "files" parameter name should be the same as the server side input parameter name
                //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#match-name-attribute-value-to-parameter-name-of-post-method
            }

            return formContent;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task API_Import_File_Should_Return_Http_Status_OK()
        {
            List<string> fileList = new List<string> { "Input.txt" };
            var form = CreateMultipartFormDataFromTestFiles(fileList);

            using var client = _factory.CreateClient();
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/import", form);

            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}

The problem is the list "xyz" is always null!
If the [FromForm] tag is removed, the response is:

StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'

If the endpoint /import is changed to handle only one file => IFormFile, everything works!
Any suggestions are more than appreciated. Thanks

Where are you calling the method API_Import_File_Should_Return_Http_Status_OK()

Its called from the Visual Studio (Code) Tests. But you can also try to call the import endpoint via postman (or Swagger (if you manage to get the swagger UI to support List ) the result is always null

It is defined in Tests, but never called in the code posted.  It is a method and must be called to execute.

In Minimal APIs, file uploads support using IFormCollection, IFormFile, and IFormFileCollection in .NET 8. Notice, List<IFormFile> does not support so that you need change your code to:
static async Task<IResult> Import([FromForm] IFormFileCollection xyz)
{
    if (xyz == null || xyz.Count == 0)
    {
        return Results.BadRequest("No files were provided.");
    }
    foreach (var file in xyz)
    {
        // ...
    }

    return Results.Ok();
}


You saved my day! Thanx. Where can one find this information? Also Swagger is working now ! Thanx

Hi @user1911091, check the official document for what's new in different version:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-8.0?view=aspnetcore-8.0#binding-to-forms
